# In the comparison test, why are the summands in both the smaller and larger series required to be non-negative for all n?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the algorithm not well-defined if either one of the series has negative summands?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at the proof of the criterion?

Comment: Hi @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, yes, several times over the past 3 years, in fact.  I was more after some examples - like what joriki provided below.  Reading the proofs over and over again I realize just doesn't really bring the point home for me.  (I am a big reader too, and my profs and classmates always warn to not read so much.  I find solving problems and starting a discussion from scratch to review these fundamental theorems that I have studied for so long...a much better way to review.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that you're asking about the (direct) comparison test in which given $0\le a_n\le b_n$, the convergence of $\sum_na_n$ is deduced form the convergence of $\sum_nb_n$.

The title seems to imply that the summands of either series could individually be required to be non-negative. However, $a_n\le b_n$ implies that the $b_n$ are non-negative if the $a_n$ are, so there is really only one question here, namely why the $a_n$ are required to be non-negative. Consider $a_n=-1$ and $b_n=1/n^2$. Then $\sum_na_n$ diverges and $\sum_nb_n$ converges despite $a_n\le b_n$.

Now you might say, but why don't we just consider the absolute values then? Consider $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n/n$. Then $\sum_na_n$ diverges and $\sum_nb_n$ converges despite $\left|a_n\right|\le\left|b_n\right|$.

Now you might say, why don't we consider $\left|a_n\right|\le b_n$ then? We could do that, but it adds nothing new, since we know that every absolutely converent series is convergent, so we might as well apply the standard comparison test to $\left|a_n\right|$ and then deduce the convergence of $a_n$ from its absolute convergence.

Comment: Awesome answer, @joriki.  Thanks so much for these great examples to keep in mind.  Have a great day.

Comment: @Lebron: Thanks. I added one more paragraph about the intermediate possibility of taking absolute values of one series but not the other.